# Removing the empty list element within a list of lists

Tags: python, nested-lists

**I have a nested list of lists like below.**

```
[['eggplant', ['little', 'added']],
 ['proportions', ['limited', 'vegetables']],
 ['vegetables', ['proportions']],
 ['foods', ['other']],
 ['meat', []],
 ['starch', []]]
```

**I'm trying to filter out the lists that have an [] (empty) element associated with them. so my desired out put would be**

```
[['eggplant', ['little', 'added']],
 ['proportions', ['limited', 'vegetables']],
 ['vegetables', ['proportions']],
 ['foods', ['other']]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickly done with a list comprehension used as a filter:

```
a = [['eggplant', ['little', 'added']],
 ['proportions', ['limited', 'vegetables']],
 ['vegetables', ['proportions']],
 ['foods', ['other']],
 ['meat', []],
 ['starch', []]]

b = [x for x in a if x[1]]

for x in b:
    print(x)
```

prints:

```
['eggplant', ['little', 'added']]
['proportions', ['limited', 'vegetables']]
['vegetables', ['proportions']]
['foods', ['other']]
```